# Post Multiple Parameters Without DTO Class

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have an action on my web project which calls to an API

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExpireSurvey(int id)
    {
        var token = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);

            var path = "/api/forms/ExpireSurvey";
            var url = Domain + path;
            var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id);
            HttpContent httpContent = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            var response = await client.PutAsync(url, httpContent);

            return Json(response);
        }
    }
```

In the API project this is received as follows:

```
[HttpPut]
    public IActionResult ExpireSurvey([FromBody] int surveyId)
    {
        _repository.ExpireSurvey(surveyId, expiryDate);
        return Ok();
    }
```

This works fine - however, say I want to pass in an int id and a DateTime variable, how do I serialise and pass them both into the HttpContent? I can do it with a DTO object, but I don't want to be setting up DTO objects when there is only two fields.

Comment: `using (var client = new HttpClient())` is not the best option, look for it!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use anonymous types like this

```
var x = new { id = 2, date = DateTime.Now };
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(x);
```

When receiving the data, you can only have one [FromBody] parameter. So that doesn't work for receiving multiple parameters (unless you can put all but one into the URL). If you don't want to declare a DTO, you can use a dynamic object like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Post([FromBody] dynamic data)
{
    Console.WriteLine(data.id);
    Console.WriteLine(data.date);
}
```

Don't overdo using anonymous types and dynamic variables though. They're very convenient for working with JSON, but you lose all type checking which is one of the things that makes C# really nice to work with.

Comment: and that will map across fine to the API with `[HttpPut]
    public IActionResult ExpireSurvey([FromBody] int id, DateTime date)` ?

Comment: No. I've expanded my answer to cover receiving the data as well.

Answer (score 7):

I think it would be helpful to recognize that ASP.NET Core is REST-based and REST fundamentally deals with the concept of *resources*. While not an unbreakable rule, the general idea is that you should have what you're calling DTOs here. In other words, you're not posting distinct and unrelated bits of data, but an *object* that represents something.

This becomes increasingly important if you start mixing in things like Swagger to generate documentation for your API. The objects you create become part of that documentation, giving consumers of your API a template for follow in the development of their apps.

Long and short, I'd say embrace the concept of resources/objects/DTOs/whatever. *Model* the data your API works with. It will help both you as a developer of the API and any consumers of your API.

Comment: Thanks for the info. What about when there is only one field? Such as Id? Do you still recommend setting up a DTO for the Id?

Comment: No, in that case, the object is the scalar. In particular with ids, though, the id by definition identifies the resource, so it doesn't need to be its own resource itself.

Answer (score 7):

You can pass multiple parameters in as URL as below example

> Parameter name must be the same (case-insensitive), If names do not
>   match then values of the parameters will not be set.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("{surveyId}/{expiryDate}")]
public IActionResult Post(int surveyId, DateTime expiryDate)
{
    return Ok(new { surveyId, expiryDate });
}
```

Call URL

```
http://localhost:[port]/api/[controller]/1/3-29-2018
```

Comment: Ah, yes I forgot about this method! This is not sending the data in the body though is it?

Comment: Yes, it sends only what you pass in the URL as parameters, and don't send form body data

Comment: Is this bad practice for Post/Put? I feel like I've read somewhere before to only use URL parameters for Get requests?

Comment: If you have a sensitive data or have many parameters don't use it, it's better to use post with DTO or model

Comment: Thanks so much! This seems to work fine for me:

[HttpPost]
        [Route("endpoint/{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> RegisterUserDevice([FromBody]Model myModel, int id)

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the line

```
var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(id);
```

with

```
var data = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject((surveyId, expiryDate)), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
```

The trick is that you use a *Tuple object containig your parameters as a single parameter.*

You should use the Tuple type on the the server side as well. It could look like:

```
[HttpPost]
public Task MyWebApiMethod([FromBody] (int SurveyId, DateTime ExpiryDate) parameters)
{
    int surveyId = parameters.SurveyId;
    DateTime expiryDate = parameters.ExpiryDate;
    // Process your parameters ...
}
```

I do not have Visual Studio now and sorry if there are any compilation issues etc.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answers above, I got the following code working. Hope this helps someone! (thanks to others of course for getting me on the right track)

```
/// <summary>
/// Post api/dostuff/{id}
[HttpPost]
[Route("dostuff/{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> DoStuff([FromBody]Model model, int id)
{
    // Both model and id are available for use!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for providing this - good to know this is possible

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with a dictionary

```
Dictionary<int, object> dict = new Dictionary<int, object>();
dict["id"] = 1
dict["date"] = DateTime.Now;

JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dict);
```

Comment: Interesting! Why is it Dictionary<string, object> and not <int, DateTime> ?

Comment: @egmfrs my bad. should be int

Comment: No, you were right, it doesn't work any other way. Does string refer to the field names, and object refer to whatever they are holding?

Comment: @egmfrs oh dang...I confused myself at one point. Yes it should be string! the string refers to the field name and object refers to value. Since you need int + datetime so it should be object

Comment: Hmm.. for some reason date is getting passed to the API but id is 0.

Comment: My serialised data is `"{\"surveyId\":2163,\"expiryDate\":\"2018-03-29T15:53:52.5796476Z\"}"`

Comment: @egmfrs well your serialized data looks right. You will need to find out why its not working on the server side.