# .NET Core 2 endpoint doesn't bind parameters for FromBody on POST

Tags: javascript, angular, post, asp.net-core

I'm doing the following call in my Angular application.

```
this._client.post(
  "http://localhost:4300/api/Beep",
  { name: name, email: email })
  .subscribe(...);
```

I also tried with explicit header config.

```
this._client.post(
  "http://localhost:4300/api/Beep",
  { name: name, email: email }),
  { headers: new HttpHeaders({ "Content-Type": "application/json" }) }
  .subscribe(...);
```

The breakpoint is caught in the following method.

```
[HttpPost("Beep")]
public IActionResult RequestNetwork(
  [FromBody]string name, 
  [FromBody]string email)
{
  ...
  return Ok();
}
```

The problem is that both fields are null.

I'm not entirely sure if I'm doing something stupid in the call on frontend side or backend side. I verified the code versus blogs like [this one](https://andrewlock.net/model-binding-json-posts-in-asp-net-core/). My bet is on the former because I followed the [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/http#making-a-post-request) and, also, I ran Postman (setting the *Content-Type* to *application/json* and sending *{name:"qqq",email:"www"}* as raw). Same result for every combination of parameters I've tried.

Under that assumption, I've been googling for anything that resembles "*binding core post frombody*" including the variations I could think of. I haven't found anything that I'd recognize as related nor useful (possibly due to lack of experience or frustration).

What could be the issue here and what should I be looking for specifically to resolve it (or at least get deeper into whatever mistake I'm stuck on)?

Comment: I think that is [HttpPost,ActionName("Beep")] but I don't know if you must use a class

Comment: The `FromBody` attribute can only be used once in a endpoint parameter list. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api#using-frombody

Comment: @R.Richards That info is from 2013 and for the old version of .NET. Are you certain it's still valid today? If so, how should I approach sending in multiple values (strings and int only, no complex structures, luckily)? I've noticed that I could use *[FromBody] dynamic data* and then *data.name* or *data.email* but I prefer to use the actual types. Can you suggest another *FromXxx* to send in a few values by POST?

Comment: @Eliseo No, it's not. Or, rather, it is but I'm already making it to the action since the breakpoint is hit. I'm trying to figure out the binding of the data not the targetting of the endpoint. Or did I misread your point?

Comment: Sorry, I use a the meta as I posted it and use a class and not two [FromBody] and work for me. I have not so experience to make something different.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana Sorry!! I didn't look at the date on the page when I added that link. It still applies today. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#bind-formatted-data-from-the-request-body). This has always been the case with the `FromBody` attribute. Looks like you got your answer. Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a class

```
public class DataType
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string email { get; set; }
}

//in your api
[HttpPost, ActionName("Beep")]
public IActionResult RequestNetwork([FromBody]DataType value)
{
  string name=value.name;
  string email=value.email;
  ...
  return Ok();
}
```

Comment: First of all: +1 for neat formatting. Is that the only way? I'd prefer to alter the data provided by simply changing the signature of the endpoint without redesigning the model. Perhaps I'm just not used to the approach? I've expected the great .NET Core to be as convenient as being able to bind up the individual fields to the in-parameters somehow. Was I regrettably mistaken?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49558987/pass-multiple-parameters-in-a-post-api-without-using-a-dto-class-in-net-core-mv (you can use dynamic or parameters in the url

Comment: @Eliseo: This kinda beats the idea behind having a strong typed language

Comment: Yes, I hate "dynamic", but it's only a personal opinion